# Unable to access report created on account ,duplicate record item

Tags: custom-report-type, custom-reports

Created report for duplicate accounts, created on account and duplicate record item.
getting "You don’t have sufficient privileges to perform this operation" error while accessing report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Insufficient Privileges error for Reports I have permission to read**

> There are a variety of reasons why you might receive an error message
>   when you try to run a report that you should be able to access.

**Possible causes might include**

- Field-Level Security
- Profile and User permission

**Check the Following**

- First, make sure your Report Type is in "deployed" status.
- Verify that you still have access to the Report Folder.
- Make sure you have 'Read' access to all of the objects that the
  report references.
- If it is an Administrative report, verify that the "View Setup and
  Configuration" permission is on your profile.
- Check the Field Level Security of the Lookup or Master-Detail
  Relationship field to ensure that your Profile allows you visibility
  into that field.
- Check the Field Level Security for every field that is on your report
  and in the object you are referring to.
- Confirm that the 'Report Builder' is on the affected User's Profile.
- If the report is built on multiple objects, make sure that a Lookup
  Field between two of the Objects is not hidden by Field Level
  Security.
- If the Report Type is 'Opportunities with Products' verify that the
  affected user does has at least 'Read' access to the Price Book
  object.
- For Communities, Customer Portal or Partner Portal Users, make sure
  that appropriate Sharing Rules are defined.

Reference:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005189&type=1

Comment: Org wide defaults wouldn't cause that specific error, but the rest of this is good.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox for your great suggestion. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @SarathBhusarapu Welcome :) You can mark it as your answer as it has solved your problem by checking the correct mark beside the answer.